# Generic parameter 'Self' could not be inferred swift

Tags: swift

```
 print("ISBN: "+self.currentISBN!+"  ID:"+book_id!, +" Title:"+book_title!);
```

Get the error: Generic parameter 'Self' could not be inferred 
What to do? any ideas?

Comment: You need to provide more context. Where is this line of code? Post a bit more relevant code.

Comment: `self` can be used in several ways in Swift, @Crissy. I made a guess as to how you might be using it to come up with my answer. I got the same error when I set up some test code to play with it, so it seems like I guessed right. In your future questions, though, give us as much as you can that relates to the issue you're having. In this case, since the error includes the `Self`, you could have included code about what the `self` represents, for example. Welcome to Stack Overflow, by the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You have a comma that shouldn't be there. Also, you could use some spacing for readability, and you don't need the semicolon (though Swift will let you put it there):

```
print("ISBN: " + self.currentISBN! + "  ID:" + book_id! + " Title:" + book_title!)
```

2) Try using string interpolation instead of all those plus's. This is the Swift-recommended way to create your string:

```
print("ISBN: \(self.currentISBN!)  ID:\(book_id!) Title:\(book_title!)")
```

Reference available as of October 2017: [The Swift Programming Language: String Interpolation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID292)